# how to search for a particular string in the given string in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a string with value as '12A,12B,12C,13,14'.
I want to check whether '2A' is available in the above string.
while trying my value '2A' checks in 12A and returns as matched.
Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select * from table where ',' || col || ',' like '%,2A,%';
```

Commas are concatenated to the column to cover the cases where the element is present at the start or end of the string.